# How do I fix my logging-profile to return the correct log levels in the correct format?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly

I'm a fairly junior developer and trying to implement Logging-Profiles into my code so that different components can use different logging levels. However this doesn't seem to be working. There are two key issues:

1. Adjusting the logging level doesn't seem to make a difference to what some of the components are producing 
   I've updated my MANIFEST.MF to include "profile" and it seems to recognise this and post some entries into the log file but it seems heavily dependant on the root-level as opposed to each category. 
   Specific package log-level doesn't seem to be working
2. Some of the entries are being returned on the same line, how do I sort this out? I can't seem to find anything online with the same issue

> 10:23:18,047 INFO  [stdout] (genericClass-20) 10:23:18.047
>   [genericClass-20] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
>   javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed
>   connection for java

This is what I have in my Standalone:

```
<logging-profiles>
    <logging-profile name="profile">
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="SIZE" autoflush="true">
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="profile.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="30m"/>
            <max-backup-index value="99"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.myproject" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="SIZE"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="SIZE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="SIZE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.springframework" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="SIZE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="SIZE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </logging-profile>
</logging-profiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your configuration you should at least be getting the `com.myproject` logs in your `profile.log` file. You likely will not get any `org.hibernate` logs in that file as any global modules will always be logged to the default system logging configuration.

In the end I don't think you need a logging profile to get this to work. You would only need to define the `size-rotating-file-handler` and your `com.myproject` handler on the logging subsystem. The following are the CLI commands you'd want to use to configure the logging subsystem

```
/subsystem=logging/size-rotating-file-handler=SIZE:add(autoflush=true, append=true, rotate-size="30m", max-backup-index=99, file={relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir", path="profile.log"})
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.myproject:add(level=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=SIZE)
```

Given the default configuration along with these commands all messages would be logged into the default console and file handler as well as your `SIZE` handler. Both the default file handler and your `SIZE` handler would get debug messages from `com.myproject`.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your response. 
So correct me if I'm wrong, but you're saying that I won't be able to have the 'org.*' profiles assigned to different log levels based on which component they are linked to. 
For example, if I were using 'org.springframework' on myProject1 and myProject2 and wanted springframework to use DEBUG on 1 but ERROR on the other that's not possible
And I don't need to use Logging Profiles to separate the projects logging? 
At present nothing is returned in profile.log when I run my app

Comment: You can definitely assign different levels to different logger names/categories. Since you have the root logger set to `INFO` there is just no need to define the other loggers as `INFO` though you definitely can. _If_ you put the Spring libraries in your deployment, you can use a logging-profile. If they are installed as a module they cannot use the logging profile.

Comment: Thanks James, Adding spring libraries seems to have solve the problem!